# Proving that the range of a linear operator $A: V \to W$ is the span of the image of a basis of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $A: V \rightarrow W $ be a linear operator and {${v_{1}, v_{2},...,v_{n}}$} be a basis of the vector space $V$. Prove that $$Range(A) = span(Av_{1},Av_{2},...,Av_{n}).$$

Let $x_{1},x_{2} \in V$ and $w_{1},w_{2} \in W$ and $A(x_{1}) = w_{1}$ and $A(x_{2}) = w_{2}$.

Given that $A$ is a linear mapping:
$A(x_{1}+x_{2}) = w_{1}+w_{2}$ and $A(cx_{1}) = cw_{1}$

$w_{1}+w_{2}$ and $cw_{1}$ are the $Range(A)$.

Because the $Range(A)$ can be shown from $x_{1},x_{2} \in V$ and that $x_{1},x_{2}$ is in the of {${v_{1}, v_{2},...,v_{n}}$}, $Range(A) = span(Av_{1},Av_{2},...,Av_{n})$

Does this sufficiently prove that $Range(A) = span(Av_{1},Av_{2},...,Av_{n})$?

Comment: "Because the Range(A) can be shown from x1,x2∈V and that x1,x2 is in the of {v1,v2,...,vn}" makes no sense. The standard way of showing equality of two sets is to show that each is contained in the other, namely, that $\text{Range}(A) \subseteq \text{span}(A v_1, \ldots, A v_n)$ and $\text{Range}(A) \supseteq \text{span}(A v_1, \ldots, A v_n)$

Comment: How would you prove that $Range(A) ⊆ span(Av_{1},…,Av_{n})$ and vice-versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the basic idea:
\begin{align}
       w \in \text{Range}(A)
& \iff \exists v \in V: \quad w = A(v) \\
& \iff \exists c_{1},\ldots,c_{n} \in \mathbb{F}: \quad
       w = A(c_{1} \cdot v_{1} + \cdots + c_{n} \cdot v_{n}) \\
& \iff \exists c_{1},\ldots,c_{n} \in \mathbb{F}: \quad
       w = c_{1} \cdot A(v_{1}) + \cdots + c_{n} \cdot A(v_{n}) \\
& \iff w \in \text{Span}(\{ A(v_{1}),\ldots,A(v_{n}) \}).
\end{align}
Therefore, $ \text{Range}(A) = \text{Span}(\{ A(v_{1}),\ldots,A(v_{n}) \}) $.

Answer (score 0):

If $V$ and $W$ are vectors spaces over the field $F$, then you need to show that $\text{Range}(A) = \{c_1Av_1 + \ldots + c_nAv_n : c_i \in F\}$. You can't just work with two vectors, when $A$ has $n$ rows.

Further, I wouldn't "[l]et [...] $w_1, w_2 \in W$". You don't really care about any vectors in $W$, unless they're in the range of $A$. So, instead of picking vectors in $W$, you should only work with vectors of the form $Av$, where $v \in V$, as this is what every vector in $\text{Range}(A)$ looks like.

So, one option would be to pick an arbitrary $Av \in A(V)$, and show that you can write it as $c_1Av_1 + \ldots + c_nAv_n$ by choosing suitable scalars $c_1, \ldots, c_n \in F$, where the $v_i$ are the basis vectors you were given for $V$.